# How to escape asterisk in me.regexp

Tags: blackberry

I have a regex that looks like this:

`RE regex = new RE("([TtYy\\*])(?:([+-])([\\d]+)([dDmMhH]))?");`

It is supposed to match

```
*-30m
T-60h
T
Y
```

and so on.

but the escape on the asterisks is not working.  I tried a few combinations like single slash, grouping that sequence with parenthesis. Anyone have ideas?

I am using `me.regexp` from http://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/

Comment: RegEx Coach shows it working fine for me. Is it possibly how you're using `match()` that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Add the location of the library: http://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/

Answer (score 0):

In  [me.regexp.RE.java](http://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/source/browse/trunk/regexp-me/src/me/regexp/RE.java) there are doc comments:

> The full regular expression syntax accepted by RE is described here:
>   Characters
>
> unicodeChar  -  Matches any identical unicode character
>   **\  -  Used to quote a meta-character (like '*')**  
>   \\  -  Matches a single '\' character
>   \0nnn  -  Matches a given octal character
>   \xhh  -  Matches a given 8-bit hexadecimal character

So single *backslash* should work here, or there is an issue in lib.

**UPDATE**
I have tried pattern "([TtYy\*])(?:([+-])([\d]+)([dDmMhH]))?" and text "*-30m" and it works perfectly for my 8900 simulator on RIM 5.0

[image: screen shot with regex-me test application]

See code:

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen 
    implements FieldChangeListener {

    static final int INT_MAX_LEN = 200;
    static final String STR_PATTERN = "Pattern:";
    static final String STR_TEXT = "Text:";
    static final String STR_RESULT = "Result:";
    static final String STR_RUN_TEST = "Run test";
    static final String STR_DEFAULT_PATTERN = 
        "([TtYy\\*])(?:([+-])([\\d]+)([dDmMhH]))?";
    static final String STR_DEFAULT_TEXT = "*-30m";

    EditField mPattern = new EditField(STR_PATTERN, STR_DEFAULT_PATTERN,
            INT_MAX_LEN, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    EditField mText = new EditField(STR_TEXT, STR_DEFAULT_TEXT, INT_MAX_LEN,
            Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    LabelField mResult = new LabelField(STR_RESULT, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    ButtonField mBtnRunTest = 
        new ButtonField(STR_RUN_TEST, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH 
            | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);

    public MyScreen() {
        add(mPattern);
        add(mText);
        add(mResult);
        add(mBtnRunTest);
        mBtnRunTest.setChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (field == mBtnRunTest) {
            runTest();
        }
    }

    private void runTest() {
        RE regex = new RE(mPattern.getText());
        String result = regex.match(mText.getText()) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
        mResult.setText(STR_RESULT + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: eclipse complains about single slash, and triple slash